# Night light not working with any Nvidia drivers, what can I do?

Tags: nvidia, night-light

Recently I approved an update through the snap store, and ever since then the night light doesn't work with any nvidia drivers. I had been using the 515 version, but it's disappeared from the list of additional drivers.

I've had to resort to using the Xorg driver, but it makes the fans go crazy, even for simple things like youtube videos.

Is there any way to solve this?